# Why Google Analytics API v3 is triggering ALWAYS sampling at 50%?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have build a very simple crawler for Google Analytics (v3) and it used to work well until this week that I started to get sampled data in all queries.

I used to overcome sampling by simply reducing the date range of the queries, but now I get 50% of all sessions (aprox.), even for sample spaces of less than 100 sessions.

It seems like that something is triggering sampling, but I cannot realize what can be. Anyone has suffered similar issues?

EDITED

We are also suffering sampling when querying the "Users Overview" standard report from GA web interface (along with others), even when there are only 883 sessions and we are asking for a single day.

[image: Users Overview with sampling]

A sample query is below, where we are querying several metrics over 3 dimensions, with a sample size of 883 sessions and a sampling or around 50% (query URL is cropped, but parameters are listed on "query" key).

[image: API Query with sampling]

Comment: Are you setting the `samplingLevel` for your request? Can you share the request you are making?

Comment: Also, is response field `containsSampledData` true?

Comment: Yes sampling level is set to HIGHER_PRECISION and response returns true in containsSampledData. It also happens on web interface when querying for a single day, so not sure if sampling trigger has changed recently. I will add the query an response ASAP

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason could be related with querying ga:users metric with several dimensions, including ga:appId.

I have tried different combinations and only ga:users is returning sampled data when queried with more dimensions than ga:date.

In summary, if I query any other metric from the example with the same 3 dimensions it returns full space data.

Two weeks ago this was not happening, so I suppose that Google has changed the way ga:users is computed recently.

Moreover, as a side-effect I realized that querying users on batches is somehow misleading if you plan to compute the total number of users, because you cannot simply sum them. That is, ga:users is similar to ga:1dayUsers when queried with ga:date, and then you cannot aggregate data. Also weird is the fact that you cannot use ga:appId with ga:1dayUsers, but you can with ga:users.

We have also detected another problem after discarding ga:users in crawler. The issue is related with segment parameter, that it is also triggering sampling when used in combination with the remaining metrics and dimensions.

We collect data from several apps in the same view (not recommendable, but it is there for legacy reasons). Therefore we use a segment defined on-the-fly like "sessions::condition::ga:appId=@com.xxx.yyy.zzz".

The fact is that when we filter that way we suffer sampling, but if we use a common filter like "ga:appId=com.xxx.yyy.zzz" we do not get sampled results.

Probably the question is why we use the segment-based filter instead of standard filter, and the reason is because we need it for some specific metrics like ga:7dayUsers and related, which cannot be combined with ga:appId as dimension and so you cannot either use ga:appId in filters. Confusingly, for those metrics, when we use the segment-based filter we do not get sampled results.

Now it seems that all our API calls are returning real data.

Not sure yet however, why a default report in web interface like "Users Overview" is returning sampled data for a single day with less than 1000 sessions.

Hope this information could help someone else if having similar issues with sampling.